# pytest dependency with unused marks

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-dependency

I have the following code:

```
@pytest.mark.dependency
@pytest.mark.test_a
def test_a():    
    <test>

@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["test_a"], reason="Skipped since test_a failed")
@pytest.mark.test_b
def test_b():
    <test>
```

I have a python test file with 2 test inside: test_a & test_b
test_b depended on test_a.
Both test got a unique mark in order to run them as a single unit.

When I run it regularly without supplying any mark - all works ok.

```
python3 -m pytest
```

When I run with test_a mark - works ok:

```
python3 -m pytest -m test_a
```

But when I run with test_b mark, which should run only test_b without test_a, test_b skipped because of the dependency:

```
python3 -m pytest -m test_a
```

How can I make the dependency work only when the depended test actually ran?

Thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look for cli option –ignore-unknown-dependency in https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html.